# How to do an If-Else Condition inside a Transaction in Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I've written a transaction block in Postgresql (via node-postgres) and it's working fine, although I would like to ask if it's possible (and how) to put an if-else condition within the transaction block.

This is my current code (working as intended):

```
async function execute() {
// Promise chain for pg Pool client
const client = await pool
    .connect()
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("\nclient.connect():", err.name);
        process.exit();
    });

//Initiate the Postgres transaction
await client.query("BEGIN");
        try {
            ... <<constant declarations>>

            // Pass SQL string to the query() method
            await client.query(sqlString, sqlValues, function(err, result) {

                << Insert If-Else Condition 1 Here >>
                << Insert If-Else Condition 2 Here >>
                
            if (someCondition == 1) {
                // Rollback before executing another transaction
                client.query("ROLLBACK");
                
            } else if (err) {
                client.query("ROLLBACK");
                res.status(500).send("Server Error");

            } else {
                client.query("COMMIT");
                res.json({ "message": "done!" });
            }
        });

        } catch (er) {
            // Rollback before executing another transaction
            client.query("ROLLBACK");
        }
    } finally {
        client.release();
    }
        execute();
```

The code above is working, although I want to put two if-else condition blocks in the transaction, which will fire 2 queries if the conditions were satisfied, and if whether true or false, will continue to the `if (someCondition == 1)` condition block.

These are the two if-else conditions that I want to put:

```
if (conditionA == true) {
await pool.query(query1)
}

if (conditionB == true) {
await pool.query(query2)
}
```

Running them causes an error:
`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, with the origin being on `await pool.query(query1)`.

Removing `await` causes an unresolved promise error.

I'm stumped on how to do this part. I've been tinkering with nested transactions via savepoint but to no avail.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What's wrong with just putting in the bit of code you wrote with the if-else?

Comment: Just put your statements exactly where you put the comments for such.  Keep in mind how transactions work. The transaction starts with the first DML statement or when  explicitly started. You explicitly started a transaction with *client.query("BEGIN");* Once a transaction is started everything (at least db calls) is part of it until either a commit or rollback is issued.  Caution: if it is available in your app or IDE make sure it is turned off.

Comment: @bobflux I'm having an error saying I can only use await inside an async function, which I find weird as the entire transaction is async, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Belayer yeah, I intend it to be that way (if I'm understanding you correctly) that it's either All Goes In, or None Goes In (not the exact term, but same thought), as I want the queries to be atomic for consistencies.

Comment: Your understanding is correct: In a transaction everything succeeds or everything fails as a single (atomic) unit.

Comment: @Belayer yay! Erm, do you have an idea of what I might be missing in my code? I tried executing my original working code + the 2 conditions, but I'm ending up with errors saying ```await is only valid in async function``` on the lines where I put the if-conditions, while removing ```await``` causes an unsolved promise. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what your obfuscation layer  ( your code) needs. I can read it and have a good idea of what it is doing, but I **do not know the language**. I suggest you revise your question to include the complete error message your getting and also include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you switch to [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), you won't have to do any such transaction hacks, you will be able to use use JavaScript naturally. See [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#transactions).

Comment: @vitaly-t yeah, I just did. A day worth of refractoring, but it's worth it with how tx and tasks work. Definitely a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "await is only valid in async function"

and your code is inside an async function?

```
async function execute() {
```

but... actually no, it is inside this one

```
await client.query(sqlString, sqlValues, function(err, result) {
                                         ^
here is the function---------------------^
```

...and this function is not async, which explains the error message.

I wonder why you're using a callback with client.query and going asynchronous at the same time, since the whole point of going asynchronous is to avoid those evil callbacks. Is this an oversight? Will it even work if you add "async"? Or maybe it's because I've never used node.js so I have no idea what I'm talking about.

Note:

```
        if (someCondition == 1) {
            // Rollback before executing another transaction
            client.query("ROLLBACK");
```

I have no idea what this rollback is doing...

Comment: No, you're correct. I completely missed the function and I was calling the if-condition INSIDE the function, making it throw out the error. I fixed the problem by calling it outside of COMMIT.

Thank you!! 

P.S. regarding the note, it's a if-condition to check whether a certain constant was set to True in the query (to check if the file was already updated beforehand).